# creando decorador con typescript

Tags: typescript, decoradores

estoy tratando de entender los decoradores y me encontre con un ejemplo basico

```
class Math {
  @log //decorador me da error
  add(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }
}

function log(target: any, name: any, descriptor: { value: (a: number, b: number) => number; }) {
  var oldValue = descriptor.value;

  descriptor.value = function() {
    console.log(`Calling "${name}" with`, arguments);

    return oldValue.apply(null, arguments); //el `arguments` me da error
  };

  return descriptor;
}

const math = new Math();

math.add(2, 4);
```

alguien me puede explicar en que consisten los decoradores y me podrian dar un ejemplo practico de para que lo usaria en una aplicacion real, en que circustancias lo usaria ? y por ultimo, el fragmento de codigo lo tengo con typescript y eslint me da los siguientes errores

1. el decorador `@log`:

---

```
function log(target: any, name: any, descriptor: {
  value: (a: number, b: number) => number;
}): {
  value: (a: number, b: number) => number;
}
No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "TypedPropertyDescriptor<(a: number, b: number) => number>" 
al parámetro de tipo "{ value: (a: number, b: number) => number; }".
  Los tipos de propiedad 'value' no son compatibles.
    El tipo '((a: number, b: number) => number) | undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo '(a: number, 
b: number) => number'.
  El tipo 'undefined' no se puede asignar al tipo '(a: number, b: number) => number'
```

2. `arguments`:

---

```
No se puede asignar un argumento de tipo "IArguments" al parámetro de tipo "[a: number, b: number]"
```

entiendo que los decoradores son experimentales pero es bueno aprender para estar preparado en algun futuro, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que saber es que siempre es bueno leer la [documentación](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators). Si nos damos una leída podemos encontrar la información que a continuación se abarca de una forma muy resumida (tomando lo más básico).

## Decorators

> Un *Decorator* es un tipo especial de declaración que se puede adjuntar a una declaración de clase, método, descriptor de acceso -los famosos *getters*-, propiedad o parámetro. Los decoradores utilizan la forma `@expression`, donde la expresión debe evaluar una función que se llamará en tiempo de ejecución con información sobre la declaración decorada.

En otras palabras y poniéndolo de una forma sencilla, es una función que nos permite encapsular algo para agregar funcionalidades extra y/o cambiar su comportamiento; lo anterior dependiendo de dónde se utilce.

### Decorator Factory

> [...] Un *Decorator Factory* es una función que devuelve la expresión que será llamada por el decorador en tiempo de ejecución.

Básicamente podemos utilizarlo cuando queremos obtener un comportamiento diferente según los argumentos que le pasemos a la función. Lucen de la siguiente manera:

```js
function decorador(value: any) {
  // este es decorator factory, dependiendo de tu lógica
  // estableces el tipo de decorador a retornar
  return function (target: any) {
    // este es el decorador
    // aquí trabajas con 'target' y 'value'...
  };
}
```

### Ejemplo

Ya que tenemos un conocimiento básico sobre lo que son los decoradores y su aplicación, podemos continuar con el ejemplo, me tomé la libertad de renombrar la clase `Math` por `Calculator`.

```js
class Calculator {
  @log({showTime: true})
  public static add(a: number, b: number) {
    return a + b;
  }


  @log()
  @validate
  public static divide(a: number, @required b?: number){
    return a / b!;
  }
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior se observa el uso de los decoradores de método y parámetro.

En el caso de `@log()` tenemos un *decorator factory*, que apoyado de la interfaz `logOptions` nos permite indicar si el *logueo* mostrará la hora o no.

```js
interface logOptions {
  showTime?: boolean;
}

function log(options?: logOptions) {
  return function log(target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    let method = descriptor.value;
    let time = options && options!.showTime ? new Date().toTimeString().split(' ')[0] : '';
    
    descriptor.value = function(...args: unknown[]) {
      console.log(`${time ? `${time}: ` : ''}Calling ${propertyKey}(${args.join(', ')})`);

      return method.apply(this, args);
    }

    return descriptor;
  };
}
```

Para el caso del decorador `@validate`, tenemos un decorador de método y para el decorador `@required` uno de parámetro. Ambos ejemplos son tomados de la [documentación original](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#parameter-decorators).

```js
function required(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol, parameterIndex: number) {
  let existingRequiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyKey) || [];
  existingRequiredParameters.push(parameterIndex);
  Reflect.defineMetadata( requiredMetadataKey, existingRequiredParameters, target, propertyKey);
}

function validate(target: any, propertyName: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
  let method = descriptor.value!;

  descriptor.value = function () {
    let requiredParameters: number[] = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(requiredMetadataKey, target, propertyName);
    if (requiredParameters) {
      for (let parameterIndex of requiredParameters) {
        if (parameterIndex >= arguments.length || arguments[parameterIndex] === undefined) {
          throw new Error('Missing required argument');
        }
      }
    }
    return method.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  return descriptor;
}
```

El decorador `@validate` validará que el número de argumentos sea el mismo que los marcados como requeridos. He dejado la firma de la función `divide(a: number, b?: number)` con el parámetro `b` marcado como opcional pero decorado con `@requiered` a propósito, para mostrar de forma simbólica lo que sucedería cuando los decoradores entren en acción. En la práctica, esto no suele ser muy común.

#### Resultados

Ahora veamos lo que sucede cuando hacemos uso del método `.add()`.

```js
let x = Calculator.add(2, 4);
/* Obtenemos esta salida en consola debido a que la función
del decorador @log() es justamente esa, loguear la llamada.

Console output:
03:11:01: Calling add(2, 4)
~~~~~~~~~> La hora es mostrada debido a showTime:true */

console.log(x);
/* Esta salida muestra el resultado de la operación anterior,
solo el valor y nada más.

Console output:
6 */
```

Ahora observemos el comportamiento del método `.divide()`.

```js
console.log(Calculator.divide(1, 2));
/* Debido a que estamos imprimiendo directamente
el resultado sin asignarlo a una varibale obtenemos la siguiente salida

Console output:
Calling divide(1, 2)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> Salida proporcionada por @log(),
                      se puede observar la ausencia de
                      la hora debido a que no pasamos ningún
                      objeto de opciones
0.5
~~~> Salida proporcionada por el console.log() en donde
     la función Calculator.divide() es llamada. Si se
     hubiera hecho una asignación, esta salida no sería
     mostrada.
*/

console.log(Calculator.divide(1));
/* Por último esta llamada nos mostrará un error debido
al decorador @required en el parámetro b y al decorador
@validate que se encarga de validar los parametros marcados
con @required. Algo como lo siguiente:

Console output:
Error: Missing required argument
    at Function.descriptor.value
    ...
*/
```

## Conclusión

El uso de decoradores, aunque es experimental en TypeScript tiene ya muchas implementaciones en librerías y aplicaciones, debido a las utilidades que representan. Especialmente se volvieron populares con Angular 2+ y se encuentran en la [fase 2 de propuestas de JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposals#stage-2), por lo que posiblemente se pueda hacer uso del beneficio que ofrecen fuera de TS muy pronto.

Hablando ya de usos en aplicaciones reales, puedes pasarte por el repositorio de [`class-validator`](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator), la cual es una librería que permite hacer uso de validaciones a través de decoradores. Muy útil por ejemplo cuando trabajas con modelos, en los que para realizar ciertas operaciones (digamos en un CRUD de una API) necesitas que los datos se encuentren de una forma antes de poder hacer cualquier tipo de operación.

Otra librería con la que he trabajado y puedo mencionar que hace uso de decoradores es [`routing-controllers`](https://github.com/typestack/routing-controllers). Básicamente nos permite crear controladores (ya sea con Express o Koa) de una forma muy sencilla y estructurada y con una sintaxis similar a Asp.NET o Java.

Y pues como mencioné en párrafos anteriores, los decoradores en Angular son de mucha utilidad pues permiten inyección de dependencias entre muchas otras cosas, aprovechando también [`metadata`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata).

Probablemente parezca difícil, pero creéme que cuando tienes la necesidad de utilizarlos, deja de ser un tema de miedo y pasa a ser uno bastante interesante. Muchas librería que hacen uso de los decoradores, tienen sus propias guías y métodos para "registrar" nuevos decoradores y que estén disponibles, agregando metadatos que son de mucha utilidad, pero en el transfondo, siguen utilizando la misma implemntación mostrada en la documentación.

Por último, te dejo el [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NBzRzN) en donde podrás ver el ejemplo en funcionamiento. Espero que la información te sea de utilidad y te pido una disculpa de antemano si no me di a entender. Saludos!